# integral involving dirac delta

Tags: calculus, integration, dirac-delta

Firstly, sorry for asking a physics question here, but on physics stackexchange, the moment they smell a hint of homework-like questions they click on "close" without even reading the problem...

So i'm supposed to calculate the behavior of the electrostatic potential $V$ at large distances $|r| \gg a$ for the following linear charge density along a ring of radius $a$:

$$\rho(r,\psi, z) = \frac{q}{2\pi a}\cos(n\psi )\delta(z)\delta(r-a)$$

where $n=0,1,2,....$

So what I'm supposed to do, is calculate the following integral:

$$V(r)=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{r} \int\rho(r')d\tau'+\frac{1}{r^2}\int r'\cos\alpha \rho(r')d\tau'+\cdots\right)$$

(where the first term is called a monopole term, second dipole..)

**Question 1**: what is that $n$ inside the cosine term for? Am I supposed to just plug numbers in? e.g. for the mono-term, use different $n$ numbers?

**Question 2**: the dirac delta term $\delta z$ requires $z=0$ otherwise the charge density is $0$? So I'm supposed to only integrate the $x,y$ plane, is that correct? And this brings me back to question 1, since i'm integrating from $0$ to $2\pi$ on the $\theta$ term, the whole thing is $0$?

Comment: If your physics homework question wasn't appropriate for Physics SE due to being homework, why would it be more appropriate on a *math* site? It's just even more off-topic here, and is still a homework question. I'm not necessarily advocating the question be closed, but your logic seems faulty to me.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Physics SE is a lot more aggressive towards homework-like problems, while MSE is more tolerant so long as context and the poster's own thoughts are shown. On Physics SE, even if the asker explains all of their (presumably failed) attempts, homework-style questions are still frequently closed.

Comment: That may be so, but the question is fundamentally one of physics and belongs on a physics website, especially the first question.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I agree, but still, the logic of posting here is understandable. (Note that I am not the OP.)

Comment: The nature of the question is really more mathematical...maybe except for question 1. My main question is really about the integral going to 0 because of the dirac delta inside the integral.  And to be honest most problems i see here on this website are pretty much homework like questions

Comment: OP: the first question cannot be answered mathematically as it depends on the physical context it came from. Perhaps you should go back to whichever source this originated from, and look at how the expression came about. My guess is that $n$ is supposed to be some arbitrary fixed positive integer. Your logic in the second question about the delta function is correct, but it's not clear how you jumped to the deduction that the whole thing is zero; from physical intuition it's clear that the potential cannot possibly be zero. Maybe you should be more careful for the quadrupole and higher terms.

Comment: Hint: the charge density you are integrating is non zero only for $z=0$ and $r=a$ due to the two delta functions. Use the [Volume element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Line_and_volume_elements) in cylindrical coordinates $r\,dr\,d\psi\,dz$ to evaluate $\int \rho\,r\,dr\,d\psi\,dz\,.$ (The notation $\rho(r,\psi,z)$ and the wording "ring" suggests cylindrical coordinates.) The question is off topic on PSE but not on MSE.

Comment: Correction: the monopole term is  $\frac{1}{r}\int \rho(r',\psi',z')\,r'\,dr'\,d\psi'\,dz'$. You should now see what you have to do for the dipole term also.